# Flutter plugin not installed in IntelliJ version 2020.1

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, dart

[image]When i am running flutter doctor command then I'm getting the error "flutter and dart plugin not installed". But in my plugin section these two plugins are installed. I am attaching screenshot for the both.

Comment: It shows the same error


  • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

Comment: Try to run doctor outside of IntelliJ, in the normal terminal?

Comment: In normal terminal erorr is same @Yudhishthir Singh

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run flutter using IntelliJ, with Android studio already being there on your machine. It happened with me that when I tried running flutter from IntelliJ with the plugins installed, it gave me the same error and it was resolved by installing those plugins in Android Studio.

Try installing the plugins in Android Studio. Then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `preferences` and click `plugin` then update flutter and dart

[image]

[image]